# Oracle APEX: Export Interactive Report to Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2007, oracle-apex

I have a page with an interactive report.  If I do a 'Control Break' and have an aggregate in place, is there a way I can export the results to Excel, exactly the way it appears on the page?

When I 'Download' the report, it appears as the third screen shot, which is not separated.

Interactive Report Results:
[image]

How I would like to export the data to Excel:
[image]

The format that is currently exported: 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The download to excel is always in CSV format. The file extension is not `.xlsx`but `.CSV`. So, i'd say no.
It's tough too. Even if you were to create a custom export to excel you'd have to extract the current query of the report (which is something that has finally been made easier in 4.2, but is possible in 4.0/1 with 3rd party packages). Then you'd also have to account for the control break(s) you applied, since those are not reflected in the IR query (even with `APEX_IR`).
I've dabbled with generating an `xlsx` file and made a blogpost/sample application on that if you'd like to see what it encompasses. Be aware that this is taking 'custom solution' to the extreme though (at least, in my opinion).
http://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=10063

Answer (score 1):

you could create the report in BI Publisher in Oracle, then through APEX, you can call the report with parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Actually [APEX Office Print (AOP)](https://www.apexofficeprint.com) supports exporting for Interactive Report and  Interactive Grid (and others) to Excel, exactly as you see on the screen (so including breaks, group by etc)